# Retain view before releasing it?

Tags: esper

I have this query that groups id's into sub views, and each view should have at least 3 unique val

```
select count(val), count(distinct val) 
from A.std:groupwin(id).win:expr_batch(count(distinct val) >= 3) group by id
```

Lets say I have val, 1,2,3.

The problem with this is that I can have 1000 events for val 1 and 2 and as soon as just one event of val 3 enters the window it is released.

How can I wait for at least 1 minute and let other events enter before releasing the window?

Thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to accumulate events for 1 minute and only after that check the distinct count, so that there is at least 1 minute of events? With contexts you can define your own end/terminate condition.

Comment: No, accumulate for as long as it takes to have a distinct count of 3 for each group, then wait 1 minute where every group has reached a count of 3 to keep acumulate events

Comment: After the each group has 3 distinct values, wait for 1 more minute and accumulate anything even if there are new groups or more/less of distinct values? Suggest to look at contexts to create custom end condition. Use the #keepall window to retain events and "output when terminated". Create a type for the end condition. Then create statement that inserts-into the end condition.